# Stop Visual Studio from Closing Program After Finish

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This is probably an easy Visual Studio question, but I couldn't find it on the site.

When I "Start Debugging" a console program, it immediately exits when its finished. Is there any way to have it pause when it ends without putting an explicit pause command at the end of your program?

Comment: Hope you find the answer to this related question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193469/how-to-make-visual-studio-pause-after-executing-a-console-app-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Run without Debugging" does that, but I guess you want to debug still  :)

Comment: Ah this is what I wanted. Its a pity that you can't debug with that. I'll accept your answer unless a better one comes up.

Comment: This does not work if you are starting an external program rather than the project ...

Answer (score 10):

Add a breakpoint just before the application finishes.

Comment: +1 If you dont want to make code changes + want to debug too, I cant think of anything else.

Comment: What if there are multiple exit points? (not that my console program has any yet)

Comment: well I gave you +1. Unfortunately this technique also hides the console window.

Comment: @Unknown- There aren't many good reasons to have multiple exit points in a console program. You usually want to have 1 top-level error handler.

Comment: Not always possible, I have cases where a breakpoint at the very end seems to be ignored (there was no return statement, for what matters).

Answer (score 6):

You can place Console.ReadLine at the end of the program. That will force program to wait for a newline character input. Or you can place breakpoint at the end of the probram.

Comment: I like `Console.ReadKey(true);` much better :3 (it just waits for a key press, whatever it is)

Answer (score 1):

Console.ReadKey() should do it.
It will pause the execution of your program until a key is pressed on the keyboard.

Comment: Read again this part of the question "without putting an explicit pause command at the end of your program" :)

Answer (score 1):

yes as [@matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851578/stop-visual-studio-from-closing-program-after-finish/851586#851586) said Console.ReadKey() will wait for your input after executing program, but you can use Console.ReadLine() which will terminate only if <ENTER> key is pressed:

```
void main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); //:)
    Console.ReadLine();//this will do the trick.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2019 you can disable closing automatically after finishing execution.

[Debug(menue tab) -> options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFEKm.png)

[Debugging -> general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjnP.png)

uncheck "Automatically close the console when debugging stops"