# Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application

Tags: c, visual-studio, console

This is a probably an embarasing question as no doubt the answer is blindingly obvious.

I've used Visual Studio for years, but this is the first time I've done any 'Console Application' development.

When I run my application the console window pops up, the program output appears and then the window closes as the application exits.

Is there a way to either keep it open until I have checked the output, or view the results after the window has closed?

Comment: Monodevelop does what you are expecting.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Starting from Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.4) there is an option:

```
Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console
```

The corresponding fragment from the [Visual Studio documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=vs-2017):

> **Automatically close the console when debugging stops:**
>
> Tells Visual Studio to close the console at the end of a debugging session.

Comment: I just tested this in VS2017 and VS2019. It requires both setting the subsystem to CONSOLE and turning this option off. Having one or the other or neither closes the window automatically.

Comment: This still closes the window for me if I launch multiple projects from the same solution.

Comment: I feel like this is the right answer for VS 2017 and forward. Too bad it's not in older versions.

Comment: How do I change the subsystem for a Makefile project?

Comment: I discovered that if the debugging a C++ console application where command arguments redirect a file to standard input (stdin), the window will automatically close regardless of the setting of this option.

Comment: The option is by default disabled for me in VS2022 community edition, but still console closes automatically.  @Viraj answer worked for me.

Answer (score 490):

If you run without debugging (Ctrl+F5) then by default it prompts your to press return to close the window. If you want to use the debugger, you should put a breakpoint on the last line.

Comment: If you have a C++ app and Run Without Debugging and the console window still closes, you need to remember to explicitly set the Subsystem to Console under Configuration Properties / Linker / System. This can happen if you start with an Empty Project, which leaves Subsystem unset.

Comment: You can also add the Start Without Debugging button to any toolbars/menus you want, if you root around in the `Tools->Customize...` dialog.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( The console window opens and shuts immediately, but the log pauses and waits for an additional press of F5

Comment: @lmray, did you set the subsystem as described in Trevor Robinson's comment on this answer?

Comment: The correct answer is the one by @TrevorRobinson: Here is the expanded version if you have trouble finding out where the config properties are: Right-click on your project in Visual Studio > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System, change Subsystem to "Console"

Comment: This is weird, if I run without debugging nothing happens at all. The app is not even started. It works fine with debugging.

Comment: Console.ReadKey(true); will make your app stop and wait for a key to be pressed.

Comment: This doesn't work for Makefile projects. CTRL+F5 doesn't wait for input.

Comment: Hum... this stopped working in Visual Studio 2015 (at least as default)?

Comment: If you have set Subsystem:Console and Ctrl + F5 **STILL** results in a console window that instantly closes, you might want to double check that have the **Debug** configuration selected when making your changes.

If you have another configuration selected, such as Release, when you set Subsystem:Console you will probably have trouble with a disappearing console after Ctrl + F5 is pressed.

Comment: Trevor Robinson is right. If you start a blank project, and C++ item. You need to go to View->Property Manager->Property(wrench icon)->Config. Properties->Linker->System->Subsystem->in the pop-down menu, choose Console.

Comment: Im working on VS community 2017. `ctrl+f5` not working, there is no `Properties` when I right click project, also the `wrench icon` is greyed out.

Answer (score 256):

Right click on your project

> Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System

Select **Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)** in `SubSystem` option or you can just type **Console** in the text field!

Now try it...it should work

Comment: This worked for my VS2013 Express, but the accepted answer did not. Very strange, as the accepted answer has worked for all Visual Studio versions I've used in the past.

Comment: @MichaelCalvin You have to run with Ctrl + F5 after setting this, that's the kicker.

Comment: as @JonathanMee stated you still have run Ctrl + F5. This was already set in my visual studio 2015, so the first answer was the one that helped most.

Comment: This is indeed correct. The familiar `CTRL+F5` will fail if you, say, add a new C++ file to an empty project.

Comment: Worked for me on Visual Studio Express 2015. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2022 Community Edition

Answer (score 44):

Here is a way for C/C++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define WINPAUSE system("pause")
#endif
```

Put this at the top of your program, and IF it is on a Windows system (`#ifdef _WIN32`), then it will create a macro called `WINPAUSE`. Whenever you want your program to pause, call `WINPAUSE;` and it will pause the program, using the DOS command. For other systems like Unix/Linux, the console should not quit on program exit anyway.

Comment: This method does not work in Visual C++ (unless you include some header?)

Comment: @wmac You have to include the windows.h header

Comment: I did not include any library or namespace but it run correctly, thanks a lot.

Comment: Worked for me on Visual Studio 2013 Express. :)

Comment: There is no need to create the macro--just call system("pause").  Surround it with #ifdef if you must use it on other systems.

Comment: Just use `getchar()` or `std::cin.get()`. No reason to invoke platform-specific executables via system calls.

Answer (score 35):

Goto Debug Menu->*Press* **StartWithoutDebugging**

Comment: This isn't even an option in VS 2008 unless C# Development Environment was chosen. CTRL + F5 works though. You can also add this as a button to the toolbar via Tools > Customize.

Comment: If you have multiple projects set the relevant one as the startup project

Answer (score 33):

If you're using .NET, put `Console.ReadLine()` before the end of the program.

It will wait for `<ENTER>`.

Comment: +1 - Either that or `Console.ReadKey()` to just wait for any key.

Comment: Weird, this has no effect in my app. It still closes without waiting for user input.

Comment: Then your code is most likely exiting before it reaches that point.

Comment: Not a great solution if you're running tests, as they'll cause your tests to hang and never exit.

Answer (score 15):

try to call `getchar()` right before `main()` returns.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2008 for a simple Hello Name console app. cout, cin, cout, getchar(), console still closes. What's the deal?

Comment: Try putting getchar() twice if you have a cout just before getchar(). getchar() expects a char and you are already giving it with cout... Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 11):

(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) did not worked for my vs2013 (I already had it).

"run without debugging" is not an options, since I do not want to switch between debugging and seeing output.

I ended with

```
int main() {
  ...
#if _DEBUG
  LOG_INFO("end, press key to close");
  getchar();
#endif // _DEBUG
  return 0;
}
```

Solution used in qtcreator pre 2.6. Now while qt is growing, vs is going other way. As I remember, in vs2008 we did not need such tricks.

Answer (score 7):

just put as your last line of code:

```
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that (1) doesn't require any code changes or breakpoints, and (2) pauses *after program termination* so that you can see *everything* that was printed.  It will pause after either F5 or Ctrl+F5.  The major downside is that on VS2013 Express (as tested), it doesn't load symbols, so debugging is very restricted.

1. Create a batch file.  I called mine `runthenpause.bat`, with the following contents:

   ```
   %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
   pause
   ```

   The first line will run whatever command you provide and up to eight arguments.  The second line will... pause.
2. Open the project properties | Configuration properties | Debugging.
3. Change "Command Arguments" to `$(TargetPath)` (or whatever is in "Command").
4. Change "Command" to the full path to `runthenpause.bat`.
5. Hit OK.

Now, when you run, `runthenpause.bat` will launch your application, and after your application has terminated, will pause for you to see the console output.

I will post an update if I figure out how to get the symbols loaded.  I tried `/Z7` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575545/2877364) but without success.

Comment: This still doesn't support debugging, but at least it addresses the issue of not being able to see output e.g. of VLD, in contrast to **all** other answers.

Answer (score 3):

add “| pause” in command arguments box under debugging section at project properties.

Comment: This would be a great solution if it worked.  `pause` appears to only work in batch files, and while it receives input from your program on STDIN, it doesn't re-print that text.  I tried replacing `|` with `&&`, but it had no effect -- presumably because it isn't executing with a command shell (cmd.exe).

Answer (score 3):

Since running it from VS attaches the VS debugger, you can check for an attached debugger:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Debugger is attached. Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I guess the only caveat is that it'll still pause if you attach any other debugger, but that may even be a wanted behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You could run your executable from a command prompt. This way you could see all the output. Or, you could do something like this:

```
int a = 0;
scanf("%d",&a);

return YOUR_MAIN_CODE;
```

and this way the window would not close until you enter data for the `a` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Just press CNTRL + F5 to open it in an external command line window (Visual Studio does not have control over it).

If this doesn't work then add the following to the end of your code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

This wait for you to press a key to close the terminal window once the code has reached the end.

If you want to do this in multiple places, put the above code in a method (e.g. `private void Pause()`) and call `Pause()` whenever a program reaches a possible end.

Comment: when i do the cntrl+f5 it opens then closes immediately? how do you fix that?

Comment: When I hit Ctrl + F5, nothing happens. It used to work for me but all on a sudden, it stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat better solution:

```
atexit([] { system("PAUSE"); });
```

at the beginning of your program.

Pros:

- can use std::exit()
- can have multiple returns from main
- you can run your program under the debugger
- IDE independent (+ OS independent if you use the `cin.sync(); cin.ignore();` trick instead of `system("pause");`)

Cons:

- have to modify code
- won't pause on std::terminate()
- will still happen in your program outside of the IDE/debugger session; you can prevent this under Windows using:

---

```
extern "C" int __stdcall IsDebuggerPresent(void);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (IsDebuggerPresent())
        atexit([] {system("PAUSE"); });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very bad advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate why?

Comment: In the case where one isn't debugging it does nothing useful, because in this case there is no problem to be solved. In VS just run the program with Ctrl+F5 and that's it, so there's no problem in VS, and in a command interpreter there's no problem, in short, there's no problem. And in the case where one is debugging and wants a stop added code to stop is not a more convenient solution than a breakpoint, and interferes in the situations where one doesn't want a stop.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i experienced this when i created an Empty C++ project on VS 2017 community edition. You will need to set the Subsystem to "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)" under Configuration Properties.

1. Go to "View" then select "Property Manager"
2. Right click on the project/solution and select "Property". This opens a Test property page
3. Navigate to the linker then select "System"
4. Click on "SubSystem" and a drop down appears
5. Choose "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)"
6. Apply and save
7. The next time you run your code with "CTRL +F5", you should see the output.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a simple hack that doesnt alter your setup or code can be:

Set a breakpoint with F9, then execute Debug with F5.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the program. This will keep the window open until you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline for details.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

1. `cin.get();`

or

2. `system("pause");`

Make sure to make either of them at the end of `main()` function and before the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this option

```
#include <conio.h> 
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int main() {
   .
   .
   .
   getch(); 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a detailed explanation for latest Visual Studio releases that worked for me:

- Go to **Solution Explorer** by pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `L`, then right click on it and choose `Properties`. on the left side, double click `Linker` then choose `System`, then click on `SubSystem` and type `CONSOLE`, then click `Apply`.
- Click on `Tools` then `Options...`, then go to the search bar (`CTRL` + `E`) and search for `console` then click `Enter`, then click on `Debugging` then `General` then disable `Automatically close the console when debugging stops`.

After that, press `CTRL` + `F5` to start without debugging. and, Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this with apps running in WSL2. However there are two work-arounds:

1. The debug window retains the contents of the WSL shell window that closed.
2. The window remains open if your application returns a non-zero return code, so you could return non-zero in debug builds for example.

Answer (score 0):

It should be added that things have changed since then. On Windows 11 (probably 10, I can't check any more) the new Terminal app that now houses the various console, PowerShell and other sessions has its own settings regarding closing. Look for it in Settings > Defaults > Advanced > Profile termination behavior.

If it's set to close when a program exits with zero, then it will close, even if VS is told otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Setting>Debug>Un-check close on end.

[image]

Comment: OP's Q is about Visual Studio and _not_ Code

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio **2015**, with **imports**. Because I hate
when code examples don't give the needed imports.

```
#include <iostream>;

int main()
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```