# cin.get() is non-blocking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, console-application

I have the same problem as mentioned in the linked question. The console window (in VS 2010) disappears immediately after running the program. I use a cin.get(); at the end of the main function, but the problem still remains. Any idea about the possible reason? You can check out the code in main:

```
int main()
{
    const int arraysize = 10;
    int order;
    int counter;
    int a[arraysize] = {2,6,4,45,32,12,7,33,23,98};

    cout<<"Enter 1 to sort in ascending order\n"
        <<"Enter 2 to sort in descending order\n";
    cin>>order;
    cout<<"Data items in original order\n";

    for(counter=0;counter<arraysize;counter++){
        cout<<setw(4)<<a[counter];
    }

    switch (order){
        case 1: cout<<"\nData items in ascending order\n";
                selectionSort(a, arraysize, ascending);
                break;
        case 2: cout<<"\nData items in descending order\n";
                selectionSort(a, arraysize, descending);
                break;
        default: return 0;
    }

    for(counter=0;counter<arraysize;counter++){
        cout<<setw(4)<<a[counter];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

link : [C++ on Windows - the console window just flashes and disappears. What's going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164077/c-on-windows-the-console-window-just-flashes-and-disappears-whats-going-on)

Comment: Have you run this in the debugger to check that a) it's getting to the `cin.get()` line and b) that it waits at that line for input?

Comment: What if `default: return 0;` is being hit?

Comment: I have made debugging and it seems not to wait for an input. ChrisF you are correct. But I cannot still figure out the reason.

Comment: In that case step through **the entire program** on the debugger to see why not. I suspect @sharptooth is correct.

Comment: Sharptooth is correct, but if order is 1 or 2 the behavior is still reproduced. I updated my answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying the title in order to be easier to find by others experiencing the same problem.

Comment: As an aside, if you want the console window to persist until the user presses a button you can always run without the debugger in visual studio by pressing Ctrl-F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that

```
default: return 0;
```

get executed.

EDIT:

You're right, that's not the issue. Read [this](http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html).

The quick fix is:

```
cout<<endl;
cin.ignore(); // <---- ignore previous input in the buffer
cin.get();
```

But you might want to read the article for further info on the behavior.

Comment: Yes, that works and the window remains. The problem occurred as well when 1 or 2 is pressed. The default case made no difference. Thanks!

Comment: id used cin.clear() instead because this resets the error flags, so that you wont get the previous cin.get()'s errors

Comment: `cin.ignore()` is important here. `clear` will indeed preserve error flags but OP needed to ignore previous input

Answer (score 3):

So when using cin.get() after cin, you should always remember to add cin.ignore() between them .

```
cin>>order;
cin.ignore();
/* 
   other codes here
 */
cin.get();
```

It is mainly because the CIN will ignore the whitespace in the buffer, so after cin>>order, there is a "newline"(\n) in the buffer, then your cin.get just read that \n, then you program successfully executed and return. The cin.ignore() will ignore previous input in the buffer. This really help!

I am a student in China. Your question is the first one I can answer here. I once had the same trouble as you. I hope this helps you. 
Ignore my poor english and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you hit the default switch label (`return 0;`). This bypasses `cin.get()` - you need one `cin.get()` per return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `cin.get()` is reading the newline which terminated your order input? You could try calling `cin.get()` twice.