# C++ Program Required with arrays

Tags: c++

I want to write a program which will show the numeric value of odd, even & zero values in array. The problem is that when I input values in array, C++ compiler doesn’t view the result and finishes the output window . Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  What do you mean by "view the result", and "finishes the output box"?

Comment: Solution: Seven.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. Your question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please re-read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and revise your question.

Comment: Takico probably meant [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/)

Comment: You need to give some context to your questions, see [here](http://ledohoanglong.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/start-at-stackoverflow-writing-good-question-answer/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean why the console window closes, you can add cin.get() to the end.