# Why doesn't my console wait for an input in VS2010 and Windows7?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, opencv

The main function goes like this:

```
void main( int argc, char** argv ){
    // validate that an input was specified
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printUsage();
        return;
    }

    if( !strcmp(argv[1], "train") ) learn();
    else if( !strcmp(argv[1], "test") ) recognize();
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown command: %s\n", argv[1]);
        printUsage();
    }
}
```

When I execute the program the console disappears as soon as it appears.

Thanks so much for your patience and help! :)

Nil

Comment: I think you are confusing program arguments with user console input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program doesn't use user input, but uses program arguments.

This program need 1 input argument that you can set that in these ways:

1. open `cmd`, change directory(`cd`) to the where the exe file exists, and run the program with arguments. e.g. `main.exe train`
2. on vs2010, go to project properties, under "Configuration Properties" find Debugging and set the "Command Arguments" to what argument you want.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't my console wait for an input in VS2010 and Windows7?

Because you don't instruct it to wait for input.

Try `system("pause");` or `getchar()` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just hit 'Ctrl+F5' and by default will wait for you to hit enter in order to close the console rather than adding code such as 'pause', `getchar()` or similar. See this SO post: [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/visual-studio-console-app-prevent-window-from-closing)

Answer (score 0):

By debugging (press F5) the console app, VS won't call 'pause' automatically after your app finishes. You can RUN (press CTRL+F5) the app, and VS would call 'pause' for you.