# Visual Studio C++ -> Local Windows Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, output

While running a program in Visual Studio C++ editor, when i click on Local Windows Debugger, the command prompt window opens up, where i am asked to input data (depending on my program). The problem is the window doesn't stay very long after the output is shown.

What do i need to do to keep the window up for a longer time, or at least until i close the window myself?

I tried for over half hour to check various options and see if there is anything that can be done to prolong the duration.

Thanks and regards,
Nikhil Kenvetil

Comment: Are you talking about a console application that closes after it is finished when run from the debugger? Normally you solve that problem by requiring a cin at the end of your main although you can also put a breakpoint there as well.

Comment: Put a 'getchar' at the end ...so it will wait till you enter a character

Comment: just put a breakpoint at end of main

Comment: @drescherjm i am taking about the Local Windows Debugger button. I am not sure what the technical term is for this. I am new to C++ :(

Comment: @bapusethi, getch hasn't worked. The window just compiles the code, displays the output for a split second and goes off

Comment: So, i was watching a tutorial video in YouTube, and when he compiles the prg, it comes with the output window, and has the option "Press any key to continue" on it. I don't get that. sorry to sound very novice, but i am.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/visual-studio-console-app-prevent-window-from-closing

Comment: do you want to review my code? i have tried all the things you've asked, but it is simply not working.its driving my MAD! its a simple prg to find the prime numbers between two numbers (range)..

Comment: Please post your main() function. Also do you know you could just open a cmd.exe window and cd to to the location of your executable and run it from there by typing its name.

Comment: void main()
{
    int num,i,j,prime;
 char y;
 char choice;
    cout<<"Enter the upper limit :";
    cin>>num;

    cout<<"Prime numbers till "<<num<<" are :2, ";

 
  for(i=3;i<=num;i++)
  {
   prime=1;
   for(j=2;j<i;j++)
   {
    if(i%j==0)
    {
     prime=0;
     break;
    }
   }
 
      if(prime==1)
       cout<<i<<", ";
  }
  
   
}

Comment: sorry, i dunno how to format it here

Comment: IT's alright.. i checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/visual-studio-console-app-prevent-window-from-closing

Exactly what i am looking for!!

Comment: BTW, You should have edited your original post and added the source code instead of a comment. Comments are not really good for posting more than a line or 2 of code.

Comment: agreed. thank you very much for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of the below methods to add some codes at the end of the `main()` function:

1. `getchar();`
2. `char ch;
   cin>>ch;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    getch();    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try using system("PAUSE");