# How to prevent output screen from disappear in Visual Studio 2013 C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013. When I compile C, it doesn't show me my output. The output screen will show up for a brief second and then disappears.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

"The program '[5688] Project1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."
I know my code works and run correctly except I just can't make the output screen stay on without exiting after a second.

Comment: Run the .exe in command line, or add system("pause") at end of program. This also happen if you simply click the exe. Because windows close the command line immediately after program exit, just add a command that will pause.

Comment: Your question title is Shows C++ and tag is on C...

Comment: @NishithJainMR: Despite the name, Microsoft Visual C++ _does_ include a C compiler. It's severely outdated (19 years) but that's still sufficient for such a simple program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Comment: Use `for (;;)` or `while (1){;}` at the end of code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can run the application in debug mode and in release mode. Normally `Ctrl + F5` will run the application without debugger. And `F5`just runs the application.

If you do `Ctrl+F5` ("Start without Debugging"), the console remains open at the end and asks you to `Press any key to continue . . .` here you can see the output.

If you are just using `F5` then you are in a debug mode. At the end you add, `getchar()` function before `retuen 0;`so the console will wait until you press any key...

Comment: I tired using ctrl + F5 but it also just flashes the output for less than a sec then disappears. I also tried using getchar() but it doesn't work also.

Comment: int main()
{
    printf("hi");
 getchar();
    return 0;
}

Comment: where are you adding getchar();? you have to add before return 0;

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it. I accidentally put it after return 0.

Answer (score 11):

Another option in addition to what's already been mentioned is to go into the properties for the project and change the `Subsystem` in the `System` section in the `Linker` options to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`. Then the console window will remain when you run the program using `ctrl+f5` (Debug/Start without debugging).

[MSDN reference for the subsystem option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).

Comment: how can you make this default option?

Answer (score 3):

There's several things you can do (I'm assuming you're using Windows):

1. Compile and execute your program using the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` program.
2. Add `getchar();` before returning to the OS.
3. Add `system("pause");` before returning to the OS.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello world");
  system("pause"); //this pauses the program until you press any key 
  return 0;
}
```

the output will be:

hello world

press any key to continue ...

Answer (score 2):

add this code before `return 0` ;

```
int  num;
scanf ("%d",&num);
```

or

```
getchar();
```

Answer (score 2):

I just put a breakpoint (F9 key) on the `return 0` statement. Works only in debugging mode, but that's precisely what you want. If you run the program directly from the command line, it already works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your screen from closing you can use getchar() as follow in Visual studio:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "Hello\n";
    getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio 2013 for Python and I also struggle with that problem. My solution is to press `F5`instead of `Ctrl + F5`, then I will have 2 pop-up windows (console and program output).

I close the console window and the other will be closed together.

Answer (score 0):

I first used the metioned getchar() and breakpoints solutions but this is no good if you want the program to end (for example if you are using a memory leak detector). I got over this by redirecting the output to a file. You can do this by inserting `>output.txt` in the command line option under the debug section of project properties

Answer (score 0):

You can also hold CTRL + F5 to get the window to stay open.