# Can't run a very basic code in Visual Studio 2013 - Operator ">>" error / build error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, operator-keyword, build-error

I have always used Linux Text Editor for C/C++ coding. 
I'm totally new to Visual Studio. I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 and wrote a very basic code.
Before I tell you my problem, I think I should mention how I opened the new project so that it's not the matter of opening a wrong new project!

So here it is:

File > New > Project > Visual C++ > Win32 Console Application > ok > (Window appears saying "Welcome to Win32 Application wizard") > Next > checked the box saying "Empty Project" under Additional options > Finish

So then, I just right click on the "Source Files" > Add > New Item > C++ File(.cpp) > Add

Then my desired window appears so that I can write some code that should work!!

### I wrote the following (very basic code) in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "What's your name?";   
    string name;  
    cin >> name;  
    cout << "Enter your age: ";  
    int age;  
    cin >> age;  
    cout << "In a decade, you will be " << age + 10 << "years old!" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

---

To run it, when I press "Local Windows Debugger", a box appears saying:
"There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?"

> > I pressed "Yes"

Then it shows another box saying "Unable to start the program....the system cannot find the file specified"

The following errors I get to see in the error list:

```
no operator ">>" matches the operands 
operand types are: std::istream >> std::string
```

I would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor. Cn u please also tell me after fixing this error,  the output window not staying after the result has come. I mean it just appears for a like a second after the final result and then disppears. Is there any way of keeping it for long?

Comment: @user3303858 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include C++'s string library.
Adding

```
#include <string>
```

at the beginning of your file should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
std::string name;
```

or include string class at the top:

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not include string class like `#include<string>`
2. Use `cin.getline(name)` to take input in string otherwise it will take just a word as input, because ">>" operator ignore white spaces (space, tab etc..)
3. When you find this Box Message: "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" Do not press **YES** because it uses the last error free build to execute your program.