# C++ program terminating before the result computed

Tags: c++, io

This program takes 2 ints (`a` and `b`) and is supposed to print their product.
It terminates without printing the last line, though:

Problem:what makes the program doesn´t give the result that u  want  and closes beforehand ? 
 is there something wrong with this line?

```
        std::cout << "Product of entered numbers = " << c << std::endl;
// first program, printing chars and multiplying 2 integers

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    printf("Characters: %c %c \n", 'a', 65);
    printf("Decimals: %d %ld\n", 1977, 650000L);
    printf("Preceding with blanks: %10d \n", 1977);
    printf("Preceding with zeros: %010d \n", 1977);
    printf("Some different radices: %d %x %o %#x %#o \n", 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
    printf("floats: %4.2f %+.0e %E \n", 3.1416, 3.1416, 3.1416);
    printf("Width trick: %*d \n", 5, 10);
    printf("%s \n", "A string");
    int a, b, c;

    std::cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply\n";
    std::cin >> a >> b;

    c = a*b;
    std::cout << "Product of entered numbers = " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean you never see the last line printed out, right? Do you see all the other lines ok?

Comment: TIP: Don't bother with C style IO. C++ streams are safer.

Comment: @Useless  :yes.. n tq 4 tips!

Comment: why i get -2 to my reputation ???

Comment: OK, and if you remove the `printf` lines (they're not part of the question you asked anyway), does it work then?

Comment: well it is the same result, print not the last line .

Comment: Maybe the program closes so fast you do not see the output. If so this is a very common problem with IDEs and there are many duplicate questions here.

Comment: Let me guess, the window closes before you can read the result.

Comment: Here is one for Visual Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Definitely my problem !in miliseconds the window closes before letting me see the output !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, you probably just aren't seeing the last line of output before the program exits, because there's nothing to keep the program running and the window open after it prints it.

Try adding something like this before the return statement:

```
std::cout << "Press any key to exit.";
char dummy;
std::cin >> dummy;
```