# How to run c++ program on microsoft visual studios express 2013 for windows desktop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm learning c++ and i just installed microsoft visual studios express 2013 for windows desktop as my compiler. After compiling my Hello World program, I can't find the command to run my compiled program. Where is the run button in microsoft visual studios express 2013 for windows desktop??
Please help! 
Here is my hello world program

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
```

Comment: Press F5 or ctrl-f5 or use the menu.

Comment: Perhaps read the manual

Comment: Note that after doing so the window will open then close in less than a second. I believe if you start without debugging (ctrl-f5) VS will prompt you to press a key. Or you can put a breakpoint at the last statement of main. There are hundreds of duplicates of this problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: how can i start without debugging?

Comment: press the control key and F5 at the same time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: Note that the code you posted is missing the final `}`

Answer (score 0):

Press F5 or click on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFPsd.png) button. And please use to learn search.