# Why is C++ Doing this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

There are no errors showing for this but for some reason just after I enter the integer from the `cin` the window closes ignoring my answer, which should determine if it says "No that isn't my fav number" or continue to a function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void printSomething(int x); //Called Prototyping, means that you don't have to have the function on top.

int main() {

    cout << "Yo,\n";
    int a = 16;
    int b = 12;

    int y;

    if(a > b) {
        cout << "Opening Function.\n";
        cout << "\nWhat is my fav number, I forgot: ";
        cin >> y;
        if(y == 10) { //If my fav number is 10 then continue.
            printSomething(y); //Calls the function. (y) is the interger called at (int x)
        }
        else {
            cout << "No that isn't my fav number";
        }
    }
}

void printSomething(int x) { //This is the function. 
    cout << "\nHey! I am the function!\n#########" << endl;
    cout << "I iz lonely.";
    cin.get(); //Meant to keep the terminal open.
}
```

This is the output:

```
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Things\Debug\Things.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Things.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x2410 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x12a8 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x2b18 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x264c has exited with code -1073741749 (0xc000004b).
The program '[92] Things.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen into a trap that comes up often when using `cin.get();` to pause the program.  When you use this you need to make sure the input buffer is empty so the code will actually block until a character is read in.

The reason there is input left in the stream is that `cin >> y;` leaves the newline(from pressing enter) in the input stream.  In order to make sure the input stream is empty you can use

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

<sup>This will pause the program if there is nothing in the input stream</sup>

For other ways to pause your program see: [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Comment: Although note that when already empty, this will wait for more input, meaning that an ignore-get combo won't work in general (to the extent of sometimes needing two enter presses).

Comment: @chris Thanks for reminding me.  I added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio run the program via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Or run it from a command interpreter instance.

Or, run it via the Visual Studio debugger (as you've been doing) but with a breakpoint on the last `}` brace of `main`.

---

You don't need

```
cin.get(); //Meant to keep the terminal open.
```

at all.

It doesn't work in this case because there's at least a newline character left in the input buffer from the previous input action, and this character is just consumed by the `get()`, without further ado.