# Can't display characters

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that should output some text, but when I run it an empty window pops up. I want to create characters on a window. Can someone tell me why this doesn't happen?

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[] = "Hello C++";

    cout << "Value of str is : " << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the window closes immediately or that the text doesnt show up? If it's the latter, [I cannot repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78421fbe85a5a59f). If it's the former try Ctrl+F5 (assuming VS due to stdafx.h)

Comment: Does the empty window stay there or does it go away really quick?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: This is impossible. It actually _does print stuff_ and closes too quickly for anyone to see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1775865/3425536)

Comment: @Incomputable It does not have to be.  `char name[] = "...";` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @NathanOliver, but trying to modify is UB, right? [According to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-and-c)

Comment: @Incomputable Nope.  `char name[] = "...";` is short for `char name[4] = {'.', '.', '.', '\0'};` and is mutable.

Comment: @NathanOliver, oh, I got it now. So, `char* str = "..."` has to be const, right? The array version just initializes the contents with the contents of the array

Comment: @Incomputable Correct.  `char* str = "..."` is ill formed.  The array form is not.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine -- but the window will automatically close when the code finishes its execution.

Consider adding a cin at the end of your code to prevent the window from closing.

```
int t;
cin >> t;
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I **hate** this trick. It adds in the source something that only concerns the development environment  and clutters code when you have more than one exit line. Any decent IDE has an option to not close the terminal window, even MSVC. The correct way is to use Ctrl-F5 or put a breakpoint on last line of main (which should be a `return x;`) and on other possible exits.

Comment: @SergeBallesta given the simplicity of that code I don't think that's much of a dealbreaker..

Comment: Doesn't matter if the code is simple or not, there are much better solutions to this problem as Serge has pointed out.