# C++: show the output from console window

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buf[20];
    cin.ignore(7);
    cin.getline(buf,10);
    std::cout << buf << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my code. From the console window, we can input a text as "I like hiking" and press enter, however, the console window disappears.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are returning before you are able to see the output. (the computer is going faster than your eyes can see the output)

For debugging purposes, you can put

```
system("pause");
```

before the `return` statement in order to see the output. (this will provide a `"Please press any key to continue..."` prompt to you to tell the program to continue after you've hit a key

Comment: I'd recommend `std::cin.get()`, no need for a system call

Comment: This answer is specific to Windows environment and will throw in any other OS.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I believe Windows is the only OS that opens a new window for output?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's not the point. The point is using this code is not cross-platform compatible and forces the code to be Windows-specific.