# Prevent console window from closing in Visual Studio 2017 cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 has built-in support for cmake projects, meaning you can just open a folder containing a **CMakeLists.txt** and use it. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to [prevent the console window from closing after running an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1775865/1896169).

With a normal Visual Studio project, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run without the debugger attached. However, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> did exactly the same thing as <kbd>F5</kbd>, that is, it ran the executable and closed the console window immediately.

Another suggestion was to set the subsystem to "console" for the application, but the cmake project has no Visual Studio project that I can set settings for.

I figured maybe I could go to the *Debug and Launch Settings* for my **CMakeLists.txt** (right click > Debug and Launch Settings > target.exe), which opened **launch.vs.json**. Unfortunately, I was unable to find documentation on this. By looking through the schema, though, it seemed as if I could set `"noDebug": true`, but this just turned off the debugger and did nothing to stop the console from closing:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "target.exe",
      "name": "target.exe",
      "noDebug": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This is driving my crazy. I can't just add a `system("pause")` to the main function, as I'm using a main function provided by a test framework. Furthermore, that should be completely unnecessary; Visual Studio should handle it for me.

How can I make the Visual Studio console not close after my executable finished, when my executable is from a cmake project?

I'm using *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.2 (26430.16) Release*

Comment: **launch.vs.json** has a `"stopOnEntry": true` which breaks at the entry to `main()`. Too bad it doesn't have something like `"stopOnExit"`...

Comment: How about building the project and then starting the built executable directly out of a console?

Comment: @Scheff That's something that can be done, as is setting a breakpoint at the end of the main function. However, that doesn't solve this problem; Visual Studio has it built in for normal projects. I want that behavior here.

Comment: This raised my attention as you exactly describe how we usually work in VS2013 (without problems). The main difference is that VS2013 has no built-in support for CMake (except our own home-brew). Thus, we always generate projects and solution files. Properties of the projects/solutions can be easily changed (until next CMake run will override it). Do you have this option for CMake/VS2017 (i.e. ignoring the built-in support)? (I tried to google this but only found "a thousand" links that CMake is now integrated into VS2017...)

Comment: @Scheff The built-in support runs cmake to generate projects/solutions under `%appdata%/Local/CMakeBuild/<workspace-hash>/build/<target>/` , where the project files and solution are generated. Those files are not visible inside the Visual Studio application, though.

Comment: In VS2013, these are XML files which you _could_ edit in a plain text editor. I guess, it's the same for VS2017...

Comment: If I understood you right, you _could_ run CMake outside of VS2017 and work the "old" way.

Comment: @Scheff Yes, you can do it the old way (I see no reason why you couldn't)

Comment: Sorry, I had no imagination how the built-in support could  work. As I couldn't help you, you helped me at least a bit (to solve a potential problem which I even didn't realize until today morning)..

Comment: Related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97664/when-running-c-cmake-project-with-ctrlf5-the-conso.html and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46678/cmake-set-subsystem-to-console.html. @Justin Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @FlorianWolters I never actually solved this; I ended up just leaving VS and using the commandline to invoke cmake.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/111915/start-without-debugging-does-not-keep-the-console.html) in Visual Studio 2017 CMake support. It is resolved in VS 2019.

As a temporary workaround, add a breakpoint on application exit and run with debugging on (<kbd>F5</kbd>):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (*New Breakpoint*)
2. Enter function name: `exit`
3. Press OK

Now if you run your project (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the debugger will stop after `main()` returns.

To remove the breakpoint, go to the *Breakpoints View* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and delete it from there.

Comment: This workaround works for me - @rustyx may appreciate it if this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this situation lately, because we sometimes use stdout for debugging info in our UI applications, we needed to turn on the console window on our dev-machines, but turn it of in our CI build.

In your CMakeLists.txt must be a 'add_executable' statement, like this:

```
add_executable(project_name WIN32 ${your_source_files})
```

If you ommit the `WIN32`, CMake will change the subsystem to "Console", which leads Visual Studio to keep the console window open when your application exits.

Comment: Are you saying that my CMakeLists.txt has `add_executable(project_name WIN32 ...)` right now, or that I should add the `WIN32`?

Comment: Yes, add_executable statements declare a CMake-Targets that create an executable. If that `WIN32` exists, it will be Subsystem:Windows and if you remove it, it will be Subsystem:Console. So, i tell you to remove it.

Comment: I did not pass in `WIN32` to the `add_executable` command, just the name of the executable and the *cpp* files.

Comment: OK, but then it should be treated like a console application. What happens if you use CMake to generate a VS- Solution and open it in Visual Studio, does the application have the subsystem Console?