# using while loop does not save data to file in c

Tags: c, file-io, while-loop

I want take input from user and then save that input into the file. In my below code if I remove my while loop then the file is appended but I want this loop so that user can enter data upto 500 characters.

```
int main()
{
    char Buffer1[5];

    FILE *ot;
    fopen_s(&ot, "D:\\export1.txt", "a+");

    fseek(ot, 0L, SEEK_END);

    int sz = ftell(ot);

    printf("Enter Data.\n");

    while (sz<500) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            scanf_s("%c", &Buffer1[i]);
        }

        // write data to file

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            fputc(Buffer1[i], ot);
        }

         sz = ftell(ot);
    } 

    fclose(ot);
    _gettch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might be handy to check that `fopen` worked. Ditto with the rest of those function calls

Comment: What if file is already filled with 500 bytes?

Comment: With the `while` loop, your program *insists* that the user enter 500 characters.  If you kill the program prematurely, so that the `fclose()` is not executed, then you might not see any changes to the file.

Comment: If you want to allow the user to enter fewer characters, then you need to implement a mechanism by which the user can tell the program when he's done.

Comment: So, How can do it?  I want to save user input in chunks.

Comment: Note: `scanf_s("%c", &Buffer1[i]);` is missing an argument, please enable compiler warnings, and this may show up other errors too.

Comment: Another error: what is `_gettch();`? This might not be your *actual code*.

Comment: It is a console application in visual studio.

Comment: @SachinKhokhar - There is a way of running programs via VS that it will ask to press a key to continue. Off the top of my head cannot remember

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: @SachinKhokhar, is there a character or character sequence that a user can enter from the keyboard that you can safely treat as a command to quit instead of data to be transferred?  Say a newline, or a five-character block containing only spaces?

Comment: user can enter any type of input from keyboard. And that should be saved to file. The condition is that data must be stored in file when the Buffer1 is filled but the user must not be stopped from entering the data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger . You are right that my program is insisting user to enter at least 500 characters. So , how can I save the user data? As it is console application . So what can be done?

Comment: Well, your requirements seem to be in conflict.  You have a program that takes its input from the keyboard, and you need to append all data entered to a file until the file exceeds a given size.  But you say you *also* want the user to be able to terminate input before the full amount of data is transferred.  How, exactly, then, do you imagine the user could signal an early end of input to the program?  I mean from the user's perspective.  What would the user do?

Comment: @SachinKhokhar, I seem to have been too indirect in my early comments.  There is nothing obviously wrong with how you are writing data to the file.  My supposition is that you do not see the result because the program has not closed the file -- either because it is still running or because you killed it early.

Comment: My exact requirement is that if user closes the application the whole data should not be lost. The data that he have entered should be saved continuously in file (like 5 char at one time).

Answer (score 0):

This implementation only works if the user appends exactly the amount of bytes necessary to make 500 bytes in total.

It might be easier to first check the filesize, then let the user enter at most 500 - filesize characters, and only after that append the userinput to the file.

Comment: what if i want to save data in chunks. Like autosave.

Comment: One way or another you have to know when the user has finished typing. Normally this is done by recognizing the enter key. scanf checks for the enter key when using the %s format and stops scanning for characters upon detecting it. Using chunks is fine as long as you detect the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define ARRAY_LIMIT 10
int main()
{
    char array[ARRAY_LIMIT];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *ot;
    fopen_s(&ot, "export1.txt", "a+");

    fseek(ot, 0L, SEEK_END);

    int sz = ftell(ot);

    printf("Enter Data.\n");

    while (sz < 500)
    {
        while (i < ARRAY_LIMIT)
        {
            array[i] = getch();
            printf("%c", array[i++]);
        }
        i = 0;
        fwrite(array, sizeof(array), 1, ot);

        sz = ftell(ot);
        //be on the safe side...
        if (sz != 500 && 500 - sz < ARRAY_LIMIT)
            i = ARRAY_LIMIT - (500 - sz);
    }

    fclose(ot);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if  we can reduce - how many times we write. That's Why I am using Buffer1  array.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but typing 500 characters is the same anyway...

Comment: actually what i was meant with write is : to write in file. I am using for loop but we can replace it with fputs. This way I want to reduce how many times we write in the file.

Comment: Are you limiting num if characters each time?

Comment: fgets() and fputs() is your solution

Comment: I want to first save the user input to a temp buffer (array) and when that array is filled write it to the file.

Comment: any Array limit??

Comment: like 10 or 20 characters

Comment: but it is still not saving the data as user types(when the buffer will be full).

Comment: No, I asked to save user input to file.

Comment: so open another file and dump the data, make sense?