# How to prevent Visual Studio node command prompt from closing on exit?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-2017

I've been having trouble connecting the Visual Studio '17 15.6.4 debugger to a browser and server code when using node as the server, and a web page with react. When I run node directly or Ctrl-F5, the site runs fine and I can see it in a browser. Running F5 to debug the server code there is a message of several lines that flashes in the node prompt when I run F5 debug and then it closes. I've tried switching the default browser.  I've tried adding breakpoints to the **server code**, `require('readline');` to read a line, and setTimeout() on line 1 which didn't work so the problem is before user code. How can I get the cmd prompt to stay open so I can read the error? Whatever the problem is might also fix whatever is keeping me from attaching manually to the browser to debug the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was broken using a small modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38492361/7100300) 
1. Create a bat file named pause.bat with the following which spawns node with the input arguments from VS and then pauses keeping cmd open:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
pause
```

Open project properties and set `Node.exe path` to the location of pause.bat

The error was:

> C:\Users\user135711\Downloads\Ghost-1.22.0>"C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" --debug-brk 5858 --nolazy
>   C:\Users\user135711\Downloads\Ghost-1.22.0\index.js (node:7112)
>   [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk`
>   are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk`
>   instead.

Changing pause.bat to

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --inspect-brk %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
pause
```

starts the server but in VS the break points don't get hit still. I have the most recent VSNT extension... hmm

---

2nd solution: I haven't verified this, but all output supposedly should be visible in the Visual Studio output window.