# Prevent visual C++ from closing automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a new project where I created a HelloWorld.cpp Source file.

But when I am running it in Start without dedugging mode (CTRL+ F5), it opens the console and closes automatically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WINPAUSE system("pause")
#endif
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" ;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Comment: I saw that post..none of them works ........but why is there downvote i tried those things and it does not work :(

Comment: It's a legitimate question. I removed the C++ tag. That was likely some of the down votes--it is not a C++ question, but a question about tools.

Comment: and your VS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Patel, did you try using the second solution on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio) linked question and then tried to use the run without debugging option? The Visual Studio will only keep the command prompt open if you set the subsystem option in the linker to console. If it is not set, the window will close as soon as the program finishes running.

At any rate, note that this will only work if you run your program from inside Visual Studio, running your .exe directly will still have it close as soon as possible. If you want your program to wait on the user, you would need to do it yourself (at least as far as I know). A very simple solution would be to write your main function like this:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
     ...//Your code goes here.
     std::cout << "Enter any character to end the program.\n";
     char end;
     std::cin >> end;
     return(0);
}
```

Note that to use the cin and cout streams, you should include the iostream header in your code.