# Creating a first C++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My IDE is Visual Studio 2017.
I am pretty new in C++ programming so I need a help about understanding principles of creating a new C++ project in Visual Studio.
So, in my first solo attempt i just chose a empty project option and afther that i chose to add new item and i write this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Afther this step and afther steps with compiling, building and a starting without debugging i did not get any message or consol window with time of code execution or option for entering any key for ending.
What is needed for getting this kind of information at the end of code?

Comment: Go to Tools->Options->Debugging and look for an option called "Automatically close the console when debugging stops" and ensure that this option is not activated.

Comment: you can also add `std::cin.get();` before returning from main. but this won't work when there had been any Input with `std::cin`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: As a side note: don't use `using namespace std;` see here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: For example in Visual Studio 2015 i can chose Windows Console Application option or creating  project and afther chosing that step i also get a App wizard where i can chse what i want  to include in project(precompiled headers) or just empty project so in Visual Studio 2017 i do not have a chance to start that app wizard.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 does not appear to give you the extra prompts. However you can easily make the changes to your project settings after the project is generated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<sub>*Converting Blaze's comment to an answer*</sub>

Go to Tools->Options->Debugging and look for an option called "Automatically close the console when debugging stops" and ensure that this option is not activated.

---

> I did not get any message or consol window with time of code execution or option for entering any key for ending

Because you didn't ask for it.

> What is needed for getting this kind of information at the end of code?

To perform input (see `std::cin` and `operator<<`)  and output (see `std::cout` and `operator>>`). Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Press enter to terminate\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: OP has mentioned that the program is being run without debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `system("pause");` you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) why. It's platform dependent and adds a *huge* overhead loading all the Windows specific intstructions.

So you should choose nicer alternatives: `std::cin.get()` for example. Which will work most of the time. Well, except if there had been input before (`std::getline` or `std::cin`). If you're creating a program with user input - use `std::cin.ignore()` twice to guarantee a "press enter to continue" effect:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> a; //etc

    std::cout << "press enter to exit - - - ";
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

also please don't use namespace std; read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

---

If you don't like this 3-liner (because it looks ugly) you can pack it in a void function and treat the whole thing as a [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box):

```
void pause() {
    std::cout << "press enter to exit - - - ";
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
}

int main(){
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```