# Console immediately closes with CTRL+F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017, I'm using C# to create a basic hello world application.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (Start without debugging) immediately shuts down without showing the output.

I've followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio) the second most upvoted answer

**EDIT**: Apparently this solution doesn't apply to C#

I've also tried resetting my settings and uninstalling visual studio. I don't want to add breakpoints or ReadLine.

Bottom line, I just want my program to not exit on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System` is on the project properties page for a C or C++ project in VS. This information is not accurate for C# projects

Comment: Did you create this using the console app template? I've always found that you need to have the output type (properties --> Application --> Output type) set to 'Console Application for this to work when pressing `CTRL + F5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create this using the console app template? If not, try doing that.

You can check that it's set correctly by making sure that the output type (properties --> Application --> Output type) is set to 'Console Application' for this to work when pressing CTRL + F5

Answer (score 0):

in a console app you need some sort of wait after you print to the screen or the app will exit. try adding Console.ReadLine(); it will then wait until you press enter to exit.
EDIT:
if you don't want to do that then run it from a command prompt to avoid the auto close behavior that Visual Studio adds.

Comment: and in visual studio when a console application finishes the console window closes. The setting that controls this was something I could find in VS2010 but haven't seen since.

Comment: @JamesLaycock If you execute the console app by pressing F5, that is what happens. But if you execute it by pressing Control + F5, the program will wait for your input before exiting. I tested this in VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Jay pointed out in a comment that maybe I used the wrong template. I don't know what template I used before, but I remade the application using the Console template and it works now.

Comment: Interesting. I thought you needed a Console.ReadKey(); statement but you're right it does prompt you to press a key before exiting without one.

Comment: Hi Jordan, I've added an answer to your question with the text from my comment that you say has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that command line arguments have **one line** only. Check your start-up project Properties | Debug | Start options | Command line arguments.