# Console Window Closing Immediately even when I Run Without Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

At my new workplace trying to setup C++. Couldn't get VS Code to work so we just installed the Visual Studio 2015 License we had and I'm running into some basic issues I've never had, the main one being that even when I "Start without debugging" the console window still just immediately closes and does not prompt a "Press any key.." message I'm used to seeing. I started off on Visual Studio 2017.

This is a minor issue, but I'm also used to having a basic .cpp file set up every time I start a new project and this does not happen, have to add a .cpp to the source files and type out int main().

The only solution I've found to keep the console up is to wrap everything up in a do-while loop but I'd prefer not to have to create one for every piece of code I write.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string tellme;
int main()
{
        cout << "enter some text" << endl;
        cin >> tellme;
        cout << "Here's the text: " << tellme << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

No Error messages.

Comment: Its not obvious.  Universal advice is to set a breakpoint on the ending } brace of main().

Comment: I'm not sure if this covers your exact version and setting, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio

Comment: What Kenny linked to is probably the best solution. I've also seen some people put a `getline()` at the end. Personally, I keep a CMD.EXE window open to run no-debug stuff from there :-)