# Parallel.ForEach exits unexpectedly without exceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am running a .NET 4.7 C# console application in which I am iterating through a collection of files (list of strings with file paths.

I want to run an operation on each file in parallel.

```cs
private void LaunchComparators()
{
    //1) Get Trade Files
    var files = GetTradeFiles();

    //2) Run comparisons
    try
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(files, file => LaunchComparator(file));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
    //2 Write Results
    WriteResults();
}

private void LaunchComparator(string file)
{
    var comparator = new TradeComparator();
    var strategyComparisonOutput = comparator.ComparePerStrategy(file);

}
```

While running the comparison, the first comparison completes and then the program abruptly stops without any exceptions.

I am not sure what I should do differently here, so that the files are all processed individually.

I am new to parallel programming/threading. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Stops" means crash or hang? Do you run Release or Debug build? What kind of application?

Comment: @aepot I am running Debug build, it basically exits without any exceptions or errors.

Comment: What about the last question? WPF? I'm asking because the app can't stop without Exception here but you don't see it. Is there "Just my code" debugger enabled, is there "optimize code" checked, "define TRACE and DEBUG" constants? Open build configuration and see it. While you're running the app there's an Output gray window in Visual Studio, look there, the Exception may appear there.

Comment: Open menu "Build - Batch build", check all configurations and press "Clean". Then run again. This is the workaround if something wrong with build process.

Comment: Ah, Console. Add `Console.ReadKey()` as last line in `Main` method, it will prevent app from closing.

Comment: @aeport But, it doesn't process all the items. I am trying to figure out that issue first.

Comment: Was ReadKey helped?

Comment: @aepot I added the console.readKey, checked the Output window, nothing stands out. 

It says the thread exited with exit code 0. But the Console.ReadKey() never gets called?

Comment: Looks like the problem is outside of the shown code. You have `throw ex;`, where are you catching it? Show more code.

Comment: `throw ex;` should be `throw;`

Comment: Also [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084067/12888024)

Comment: How do you call the `LaunchComparators` method? Also are there any `async void` methods in your application? Finally I would suggest running it without the debugger attached (with Ctrl+F5).

Answer (score -1):

Parallel For and ForEach operations do not re-throw exception that occur inside the loop. If you don't add exception handling inside the loop the exceptions are lost and the loop just terminates.

Here is a link to an article on how to handle exception inside of Parallel processing loops:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops

Comment: Why is this rated down? This is true and imho the corrct answer