# Local Windows Debugger Keeps crashing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm running into problems with my local debugger on visual studio while trying to learn C++, as soon as it gets to the end of the code it immediately closes and doesn't allow me to close it myself so I can't even see the final bit of output.

As far as I know there are no errors in my code and I tried the `getchar()` so that I could enter a character before the debugger closing.

Here's my code just incase there are errors but I don't think there are

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int search(char* pchs, int size, char key) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (pchs[i] == key) 
            count++;    
    }
    return count;
    }

    int main() {
    int size = 0;
    char key = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the size of the array" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Please enter the key (a-z)" << endl;
    cin >> key;

    char* pchs = new char[size];

    if (pchs != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            pchs[i] = 97 + rand() % 26;
            cout << pchs[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "No. Occurences: " << search(pchs, size, key) << endl;
    }
    
    
    delete[] pchs;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it with `ctrl-f5`.

Comment: Tried that, same problem occurs. As soon as i enter my 2 user inputs it just closes down straight away, no error message or anything with f5 and crtl f5

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct revision? I don't see anything glaringly wrong. It should at least get the part where it asks for a key.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OP didn't say it didn't

Comment: It does get to the part where it asks for the key, however after user input thats where it just closes down straight away

Comment: @Cbrady _"after user input thats where it just closes down straight away"_ You don't actually know that; it could be completing the program and producing the output, just not keeping the window open long enough for you to see it. Don't make assumptions. There's also no evidence of any "crashing"...

Comment: Ok. I misread "As soon as i enter my 2 user inputs" as "as soon as I enter a 2". Either way, the code looks fine and should run to completion. https://ideone.com/P1ltmC

Comment: By the way, I think `key` will always be a newline...

Comment: Side note: you are not seeding the psuedo-random number generator so your code will produce the same sequence of letters each time.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that when i set a breakpoint, was always the same but thanks anyway!:)

Comment: Try putting `char c; cin >> c;` right before `return 0;`.

Comment: That seemed to work and it doesn't just close now.. not sure why this works lol

Comment: That just waits for the user the enter any character. The real question is why `ctrl-f5` does not work for you? Do you have one of those keyboards that re-maps the function keys?

Comment: Yeah but i tried the same with getchar() to get the user to enter a character before closing and it didnt work. No my crtl f5 runs without debugging, also clicked debug > run without debugging just to make sure

Answer (score 3):

Go to Tools -> Options and search for this option and disable it
[image: Automatically close the console when debugging stops]

Comment: https://gyazo.com/342c71fb8c896f16c3b16baf475a29ce    I don't seem to have that option on my Visual Studio 2017

Comment: You are probably running an older version of Visual Studio then, but it probably is not that solution in that case.

Comment: I just remember it solving a similar problem for me in the past.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio   tried solutions on this here but they dont seem to work either

Comment: @Cbrady Is your VS 2017 version [15.9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084067/5538420) or higher? If not you should Run / Check for Updates and bring your installation up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method:

Right click on your project

> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)