# Visual Studio VS 2022 won't display cout simplest Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   string fileTxt;

   cout << "disply ok";


   return 0;

}
```

i was working on file handling C++ ifstream but i can't get the Code to open my .txt, so i start troubleshoot and removing all the Codes to only have "hello world" program remaining...
And that still won't work, all i got is a Terminal that goes off instantly...without any text i asked it to display eg. "dsply ok";

Comment: i had to redo a Project this time the simplest "hello world" work.  I duno about C++ file handling ifstream, i post an update later...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)