# How to make a C code to take more time to exit in Visual Studio 2010 or visual c++ 2010 express?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I build the code, then when I try to run it, it executes and exits quickly .
I am pretty sure that there is a way in the project configuration , but I forgot how .

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193469/how-to-make-visual-studio-pause-after-executing-a-console-app-in-debug-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found this solution that does not involve modifying your code. It contains a workaround that involves modifying your .vcxproj file.

To do this from within Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (I'm assuming it is similar for Visual Studio 2010), open your project and navigate to the following menu:
Project->$YOURPROJECTNAME Properties...
    ->Configuration Properties
        ->Linker
            ->System->SubSystem

Then use the dropdown to select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) and apply the change.

"Start without debugging" should do the right thing now.
Thanks All for your answers , but this works perfectly .

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use `getc()` before the return. Enter a character and it will exit..

Or run the VS `ctrl+f5` combination, or add a breakpoint if debugging.

Comment: I tried, 
error C2198: 'getc' : too few arguments for call ....
What to put between brackets?

Comment: use getchar(); or getc(stdin);

Answer (score 0):

A way is to stick

> system("PAUSE")

before the exit.

I must say the only time I used system("PAUSE") was at school when we were doing algorithm exercises. And I'm sre its bad pratice ^^

A cleaner way is to read the input like

scanf or cin

this way your program waits for a input in the keyboard

Comment: Never use system(); It's plain evil.

Comment: Breakpoints don't work when you use Ctrl+F5, (aka "start without debugging").  It's not a best practice, whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

Or you set a breakpoint on the last statement.