# Visual Studio 2010 Start Without Debugging issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a visual studio 2010 question.  I have visual studio solution with multiple projects including several console applications.  Until recently all console apps would open a console window which stayed open after the app finished executing when started without debugging (Ctrl + F5).  Now, one of the apps stopped keeping the window open.  The projects are under source control and nothing has changed in the settings as far as I can tell.  Also, the Linker->Sytrem->SubSystem setting is set to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) like all the other apps.
Does anyone know what else could be the issue?  I have rebuilt, closed and even rebooted my machine.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193469/how-to-make-visual-studio-pause-after-executing-a-console-app-in-debug-mode) with a bunch of answers.

Comment: I already have the console setting set and am starting with ctr+f5. This still does not work (though it used to).

Comment: Weird; have you already updated VS 2010 to service pack 1?